# What is the purpose of the "social history" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am not at all saying that we should remove these tags, and I am not trying to imply that there's no purpose in having these tags.

However I noticed that this recent question: [Have there been instances in physics where different scientists have interpreted the same data differently?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14051/8052) was tagged with [physics-social-history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics-social-history) which has only 6 questions and ***zero guidance on the usage of the tag***. When I looked deeper into this I discovered that we also have [mathematics-social-history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics-social-history), [social](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social), [social-context](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-context), and [social-sciences](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-sciences), ***none of which have usage guidance explained yet.***

For [social-sciences](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-sciences) I was easily able to make a suggestion for tag usage guidance (this is just waiting to get approved through peer review now), but for the rest of them, what exactly is the purpose of these tags and what do we want the usage guidance to say?

For now I have suggested to retag the aforementioned question (still waiting for it to go through peer review), to have  [reference-request](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) instead of [physics-social-history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics-social-history) since this made much more sense anyway, and with ***four other physics tags already on the question*** it seemed that it would reach anyone following physics tags anyway.